# How to append the dataframe data into dedicated SQL pool through Spark pool of synapse?

Tags: azure-synapse

How to append the data frame data into dedicated SQL pool through Spark pool of synapse?

Answer (score 0):

The `synapsesql.read` method (described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export)) does not currently support appending to a dedicated SQL pool table but you can simulate that behaviour with either partition switching or use CTAS to combine your original table and the new data.

Partitioning pattern:

[image: Partitioning pattern]

CTAS pattern:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.yourNewTable
WITH (
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN, -- or HASH(someColumn)|REPLCIATE
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX -- or CLUSTERED INDEX|HEAP
)
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.someTable_part1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM dbo.someTable_part2;
```

You *may* be able to do append with a JDBC connection but I probably would not do that in Synapse.  You could also try `saveAsTable` method, bearing in mind this appends to a Spark table not a dedicated SQL pool table, something like:

```
df.write.saveAsTable('yourTable', mode='append')
```

Comment: Append got added recently, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export#supported-dataframe-save-modes